# Let G be a finite group and a from G.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let G be a finite group and a from G. Prove that $o(a)\le|G|$, where $o(a)$ is the order of elements, and $|G|$ group order.

Comment: Do you know Lagrange's theorem?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Suppose $o(a)>|G|$. Then there is the subgroup $H = \{ a^k \ |\ k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, and the order of $H$ coincides with that of $a$. On the other hand, $|H|$ is the cardinality of $H$ as a set. We have $H\subseteq G$, from which it follows that $|H| \le |G|$, but, by assumption, $|H|>|G|$, and so $|G|<|G|$. From this contradiction, we obtain that $o(a) = |H| \le |G|$ for any $a\in G$.

Comment: You made my day. Thank you soo much

Comment: @NelliKuukeri it is the same to approve when the o(a)>=|G|?

Comment: @AngelTraveler you want to assume the negation of $o(a)\le |G|$, and that is $>$, not $\ge$. You see, one of these holds: $a<b, a=b, a>b$. If we claim $a\le b$, then we say that $a<b$ or $a=b$. To claim that $a\le b$ is not true is the same as to say $a>b$.

Comment: @NelliKuukeri thank you. Have a nice day

Comment: @AngelTraveler you too :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$o(a) = | \langle a \rangle| \le |G|.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Assume $o(a)>|G|$. Notice that $$\{e,a,a^2,\dots,a^{o(a)-1}\}$$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Thank youu for the hint

Comment: Yo'ure welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The map $f:\{0,\cdots, o(a)-1\}\to G$, $f(n)=a^n$ is injective. In fact, let $0\le m\le n<o(a)$ such that $a^n=a^m$. Then $0\le n-m <o(a)$ and $a^{n-m}=e$. By definition of $o(a)$, we have that $n-m=0$.